# Tkinter Python Resources

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm looking to design a (very) basic GUI for a battleship game.

As suggested in another question, I was going to use Tk's check buttons and coordinates and pass the value and so forth.

I'm having a tough time finding a decent start-up tutorial for Tkinter. I've tried Google and went through several results to little to no avail. Though I'm pretty experienced with Python, I've never done any GUI (other than lightly with Xcode). If anyone knows any good resources, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: when I google "tkinter tutorial", the first two results are pythonware and tkdocs; did you not find either of those useful? Your question would be better if you listed the tutorials you already know about and don't like, so we don't suggest things you already know won't help you.

Answer (score 1):

"Programming Python" by Mark Lutz has a chapter on GUI's.

The [tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) page on the Python wiki has links to tutorials as well.

Comment: That's an awesome book. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[tkdocs.com](http://www.tkdocs.com) has a [tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html) that covers tkinter (as well as using tk with Ruby, Perl and Tcl).

Answer (score -1):

For what you need I suggest you look at the [canvas widget](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/canvas.html)

There are several resources: e.g. - http://www.techrepublic.com/article/tkinter-canvas-freeform-guis-in-python/6310698 or http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm

Comment: The question isn't about using the canvas, it's asking for tutorials related to using tkinter. The links you give are specific to the canvas rather than general Tkinter tutorials.

Comment: For a battleship game? I think starting from canvas is what he really needs. And in any case - that's as good a start as any.